# Keep WYSIWYG on Blog Page

Tags: blog, wysiwyg

I want to use the WYWISWYG on my blog page for an introduction text, but can't seem to bring back the WYSIWYG Editor on the page the page I defined as my blog posts page.

Is there any way to force WP to still show the WYSIWYG on the Blog posts page?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pre WP 4.9**

```
if( ! function_exists( 'fix_no_editor_on_posts_page' ) ) {

    /**
    * Add the wp-editor back into WordPress after it was removed in 4.2.2.
    *
    * @param Object $post
    * @return void
    */
    function fix_no_editor_on_posts_page( $post ) {
        if( isset( $post ) && $post->ID != get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
            return;
        }

        remove_action( 'edit_form_after_title', '_wp_posts_page_notice' );
        add_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
    }
    add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'fix_no_editor_on_posts_page', 0 );
}
```

**WP 4.9**

```
if( ! function_exists( 'fix_no_editor_on_posts_page' ) ) {

    function fix_no_editor_on_posts_page( $post_type, $post ) {
        if( isset( $post ) && $post->ID != get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
            return;
        }

        remove_action( 'edit_form_after_title', '_wp_posts_page_notice' );
        add_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
    }

    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'fix_no_editor_on_posts_page', 0, 2 );

}
```

[Full Details Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/193756/86845)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick manual fix-

The problem is that the page's content is currently empty.

1. Switch the page for posts to a temporary page,
2. edit the original page and add some content,
3. save,
4. set the page for posts page back to the original page.

You'll now be able to edit it whenever you want, as long as you don't empty it again.